# php ignore ssl certificate from ssh

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, ssh

I need to retrive wordpress content from other website where ssl exipred.
To do this, using wp-cli, I run

```
php wp-cli.phar import import.xml
```

But it fails because of expired ssl certificate on the server where the files of the import.xml file are located.

How can I ignore the ssl certificate?

Answer (score 0):

open wp-config.php and add this two line to file

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://yourdomine.com');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://yourdomine.com');
```

and in your database at table options change them.
also did you use simple-ssl plugin?